# Django 1.11 new middleware and decorator_from_middleware_with_args

Tags: python, django

I've been looking to send a middleware class a parameter (name), but the documentation is really contradictory

When I try to add *args, **kwargs or a named argument to **init** I get this message: TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument

Head over to the manual and it says:

> Django initializes your middleware with only the get_response argument, so you can’t define **init**() as requiring any other arguments.

Then I find a method called decorator_from_middleware_with_args and the docs say

> decorator_from_middleware_with_args(middleware_class)[source]¶ Like
>   decorator_from_middleware, but returns a function that accepts the
>   arguments to be passed to the middleware_class. For example, the
>   cache_page() decorator is created from the CacheMiddleware like this:

```
cache_page = decorator_from_middleware_with_args(CacheMiddleware)

@cache_page(3600)
def my_view(request):
    pass
```

But how can this be possible if the init of middleware can't accept arguments?

Anyone know how to get this working in Django 1.11?

Comment: Can you expand on how you were planning to pass the additional argument to the middleware? You declare the middleware list in your settings, and then Django takes care of calling it, you normally don't call it directly.

Comment: You can't *require* arguments, but you can *accept* them. `*args` and `**kwargs` would work, as would keyword args with default values.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry - django allows you to apply middleware on the rest_framework views. This is required in cases where you need access to request.user when they are JWT authenticated. So as above, I would expect to be able to decorate the view method with @mymiddleware(name='add_test') - I currently use middleware this way without parameters.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - oh how dumb... I wasn't defaulting the arguments, *args and **kwargs definitely kills it, but you can define the __init__ with param_name=None and it's OK